# Why Doesn't Style.Display = None Work To Make My Button Invisible?

Tags: javascript, html

I wrote a simple function that calls onClick. When one button is selected it is supposed to make the next set of buttons visible of invisible based on that particular choice. I have tried multiple ways to get it to work and none of them seem to get the button to become invisible after the function runs.

Here is what I have so far...

```
function hiddenMess(){

if (document.getElementById('Selection8').checked) {
    document.all('customChoice1').style.visibility = 'hidden';        
    document.getElementById('customChoice1').style.visibility =  'hidden';   
    document.getElementById('customChoice1').style.display = 'none';
}
```

I used all 3 of these in the hopes one of them would work, and then I could eliminate the other two.

The button it is called from is setup like this

```
<div class="radio">
  <label><input type="radio" id='Selection8' name="SelectionVal" value="222"  OnClick="hiddenMess()">Test Button 8</label>
</div>
}
```

This is the button I am trying to make hidden.

```
<input type="radio" id="customChoice1" name="customDChoice"  value="Hello" > Hello"<br>
```

Comment: Are you sure your if condition ever actually runs? Have you checked the error console for messages?

Comment: That's just the code in here, I changed it from what is in my work code base so that's a typo. Yes, I'm sure my function runs. I set an alert in it.

Comment: `document.all`????? Why are you using that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is successfully hiding the radio button itself but not the label. Here we target the label, which wraps the radio, instead:

```js
function hiddenMess(){

  if (document.getElementById('Selection8').checked) {  
      document.getElementById('customChoice1').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
                 <label><input type="radio" id='Selection8' name="SelectionVal" value="222"  OnClick="hiddenMess()">Test Button 8</label>
             </div>
<br>
<hr>
<br>

   <label id="customChoice1"><input type="radio" name="customDChoice" value="Hello">Hello</label>
```

Comment: The OP says that it's not hiding it. I think we should trust that they're telling the truth. The question only states that the button should be hidden.

Comment: It's funny, it works here. But in my my own version, I still see the button and the label.

Comment: @JackParker2 the code you pasted in your quesiton is missing a closing tag (</label>). Look very carefully at your code, and if need be, copy the code from my snippet.

Comment: Missing label? I see a `</label>` at the end of that line. I'm saying that this seems like a *"works for me"* answer, which doesn't help the OP solve the problem.

Comment: @squint yes he was missing `</label>` on the button he was trying to hide.

Comment: There's no opening `<label>`. I'm glad @JackParker2 got it working but there's nothing in the question that would have prevented the button itself (not the "Hello") from being hidden.